# Display a modal dialog box on FullCalendar app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar.io version 5.3.2 in an Asp.net Core Razor Page application.

I added a  JavaScript function to create a modal dialog box to the application. My Index.cshtml file which is found at directory path: MyDemo > Pages > Calendar > Index.cshtml is shown below: -

```
@page
@model MyDemo.Pages.Calendars.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.js'></script>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>

    <link href='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css'>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.js'></script>

    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'></script>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({ 
                   
                header: {
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
                },

                initialView: "month",
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                select: function(start, end) {
                    // Display the modal.
                    // You could fill in the start and end fields based on the parameters
                    $(".modal").modal("show");
                    $(".modal")
                        .find("#title")
                        .val("");
                    $(".modal")
                        .find("#starts-at")
                        .val("");
                    $(".modal")
                        .find("#ends-at")
                        .val("");
                    $("#save-event").show();
                    $("input").prop("readonly", false);
                },

                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    //dynamically prepend close button to event
                    element
                        .find(".fc-content")
                        .prepend("<span class='closeon material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
                    element.find(".closeon").on("click", function () {
                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function(calEvent) {
                    // Display the modal and set event values.
                    $(".modal").modal("show");
                    var title = $(".modal")
                        .find("#title")
                        .val(calEvent.title);

                    var start = $(".modal")
                        .find("#starts-at")
                        .val(calEvent.start);

                    var end = $(".modal")
                        .find("#ends-at")
                        .val(calEvent.end);
                    $("#save-event").show();
                    $("input").prop("readonly", false);
                }
            });

            // Bind the dates to datetimepicker.
            $("#starts-at, #ends-at").datetimepicker();

            //click to save event
            $("#save-event").on("click", function(event) {
                var title = $("#title").val();
                if (title) {
                    var eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: $("#starts-at").val(),
                        end: $("#ends-at").val()
                    };
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");

                // Clear modal inputs
                $(".modal")
                    .find("input")
                    .val("");
                // hide modal
                $(".modal").modal("hide");
            });
        });

    </script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 40px 10px;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #wrap {
            width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .closeon {
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        input {
            width: 50%;
        }

            input[type="text"][readonly] {
                border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }

        /*info btn*/
        .dropbtn {
            /*background-color: #4CAF50;*/
            background-color: #eee;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            min-width: 200px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: -300px;
        }

            .dropdown-content p {
                color: black;
                padding: 4px 4px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
            }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: grey;
        }

            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn span {
                color: white;
            }
    </style>


</head>
<body>     
        <div id='calendar'></div>
        <div id='datepicker'></div>

        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4><input class="modal-title" type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Event Title/Description" /></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label class="col-xs-4" for="starts-at">Starts at</label>
                                <input type="text" name="starts_at" id="starts-at" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label class="col-xs-4" for="ends-at">Ends at</label>
                                <input type="text" name="ends_at" id="ends-at" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output solution appears as a blank webpage and the Console window shows the following error message and warning message: -

Error message:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index:40)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Warning message: -

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44370/Calendars/index:40:28)
    at e (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
```

[image: FullCalendar Console Error and Warning]

**Update**
I have updated the code in the Index.cshtml page and the FullCalendar webpage is now visible. I added an Add Event button and when I click on the button, the prompt do not appear. When I check the Console Window, there are no errors:-

```
@page
@model MyDemo.Pages.Calendars.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='~/lib/fullcalendar/lib/main.js'></script>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: 'addEventButton',
                    right: 'prev,next today,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                selectable: true,
                selectMirror: true,
                customButtons: {
                    addEventButton: {
                        text: 'add event',
                        eventClick: function (event) {
                            var dateStr = prompt("Event ID: " + event.id + " Start Date: " + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + " End Date: " + event.end);
                            var date = new Date(dateStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time
                        

                            if (!isNaN(date.valueOf())) { // valid?
                                calendar.addEvent({
                                    title: 'dynamic event',
                                    start: date,
                                    end: date,
                                    allDay: true
                                });
                                alert('Great. Now, update your database...');
                            } else {
                                alert('Invalid date.');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            calendar.render();


        });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-5">
        <h2 class="mb-4">Full Calendar</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body p-0">

                <div id='calendar'></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- calendar modal -->
    <div id="modal-view-event" class="modal modal-top fade calendar-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="event-icon"></span><span class="event-title"></span></h4>
                    <div class="event-body"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-view-event-add" class="modal modal-top fade calendar-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form id="add-event">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Add Event Detail</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v.title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Start Date</label>
                            <input type='text' class="datetimepicker form-control" name="v.startdate">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>End Date</label>
                            <input type='text' class="datetimepicker form-control" name="v.enddate">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="v.description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Theme Color</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="v.themecolor">
                                <option value="fc-bg-default">fc-bg-default</option>
                                <option value="fc-bg-blue">fc-bg-blue</option>
                                <option value="fc-bg-lightgreen">fc-bg-lightgreen</option>
                                <option value="fc-bg-pinkred">fc-bg-pinkred</option>
                                <option value="fc-bg-deepskyblue">fc-bg-deepskyblue</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Event Icon</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="eicon">
                                <option value="circle">circle</option>
                                <option value="cog">cog</option>
                                <option value="group">group</option>
                                <option value="suitcase">suitcase</option>
                                <option value="calendar">calendar</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The FullCalendar webpage image:-

[image: FullCalendar Webpage]

Comment: `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({` is fullCalendar v3 syntax from when fullCalendar was a jquery plugin. From v4 onwards it's not based on jQuery, and the syntax you need to use for initialising it is clearly shown in the fullCalendar documentation, samples and demos. You mention you're using 5.3.2, so you need to follow the examples for how to use the calendar in 5.x . Of course, that fact doesn't stop you from using jQuery for other things in your page, such as showing modal dialogs. Your previous (now deleted question) seemed to use the right syntax, so I'm unclear why you suddenly changed it

Comment: `I am using FullCalendar.io version 5.3.2` please check [this doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals) that explains how to initialize a calendar with fullcalendar v5.3.2

Comment: Thanks for the update. Custom buttons don't have an `eventClick` option. Where did you get that idea from? The options for custom buttons are clearly listed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons

Comment: Anyway it really makes no sense to use a custom button for creating events. Instead handle the `select` callback, which lets the user choose a time period on the calendar on which to create the event. The callback will tell you what dates/times they selected. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback.  You can then use that in the addEvent method, once you've asked them for more information such as the title (which can be done via prompts, modal dialogs, or whatever you prefer).

Comment: Also $.fullCalendar.formatDate is obsolete (and probably won't even work). Again, check the documentation to find out what the current method is called. (tldr; here it is: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-formatDate . There are also other date-related functions you could find useful - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added an Add Event button and when I click on the button, the prompt do not appear.

[This demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent-demo) shows how to add a new event to the calendar via a custom button, and in example code (by clicking "**Edit in CodePen**" at the top-right corner on that page) you would find `click` property is used.

And as @ADyson shared in comment, if you check [the doc about "customButtons"](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons), you can also get detailed description of properties that customButton entry accepts.

Besides, please note that the callback function does not accept calendar event as argument.

```
`click` - a callback function that is called when the button is clicked. Accepts two arguments: ( mouseEvent, htmlElement ).
```

If you'd like to enable user to add a new event to the calendar via a custom button, you can modify the code to use two prompt for `startdate` and `enddate`, like below.

```
customButtons: {
    addEventButton: {
        text: 'add event',
        click: function () {
            var dateStr = prompt('Enter start date in YYYY-MM-DD format');
            var dateEnd = prompt('Enter end date in YYYY-MM-DD format');


            var str = new Date(dateStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time
            var end = new Date(dateEnd + 'T00:00:00');

            if (!isNaN(str.valueOf()) && !isNaN(end.valueOf())) { // valid?
                calendar.addEvent({
                    title: 'dynamic event',
                    start: str,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: true
                });
                alert('Great. Now, update your database...');
            } else {
                alert('Invalid date.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```